# Find which range does the value lie in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have some data in this form (dictionary):

```
Value0  Text1
Value1  Text2
Value2  Text3
Value3  Text4
Value4  Text5
```

I now have to loop through an array which may have any random values.

```
foreach value in random array
{
    if value is between (value0 && value1)
    console.writeline(Text1)
    if value is between (value1 && value2)
    console.writeline(Text2)
    if value is between (value2 && value3)
    console.writeline(Text3)
    if value is between (value3 && value4)
    console.writeline(Text4)
}
```

The problem I am facing here is that the for each value of the array, I should be able to detect what range it is (greater than value 0 and lesser than value 1), and hence get the corresponding text. But, the dictionary is not a constant and can have any number of values and hence I cannot these if conditions as above.
(For eg: the dictionary might have another entry `Value5       Text6`)

what would be a decent way to do this?

Comment: You want to use an ordered dictionary then iterate through the set of entries remembering the last key-value pair that your value is less than or equal to. Then as soon as you find a key that's greater than your value stop and return. However I don't know what the best C# data structure for this is - SortedList? Or you can extract the keys from a different type of dictionary, sort them and iterate through that. (Ideally you'd want to find the greatest-less-than key without doing a complete iteration, e.g. a tree walk, but I don't know of a data structure implementation that does that either.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this using a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, because it doesn't keep the items in it ordered. But you can use a [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) (or a `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`) to do this:

```
TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>(SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    var comparer = dictionary.Comparer;

    TValue result = default(TValue);

    foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
    {
        if (comparer.Compare(key, kvp.Key) < 0)
            return result;

        result = kvp.Value;
    }

    return result;
}
```